# Hibernate Result Transformer cannot instantiate resultclass

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a SQL query that I want to map to a class.  I'm using Hibernate's createSQLQuery and then using a Result Transformer for the class I'd like to map to.  But Hibernate is throwing this error:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/mypackage].[MyPackageServlet]] 
Servlet.service() for servlet MyPackageServlet threw exception org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
Could not instantiate resultclass: com.myapp.mypackage.context.report.MonthlyReportContext$MonthlyReport        
at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:69)
```

From what I can tell, this means my constructor is wrong.  It's set to public, and it's empty.  Not sure what else I need to do here?

```
public class MonthlyReport
{
       /**  Some private properties defined here **/
       public MonthlyReport(){}  
       /** setters and getters for all properties here **/
    }
```

The SQL query works fine when run from pgadmin.  Here, I set all the fields with addScalar since the class properties are camelCased.  Then I use setResultTransformer:

```
    Query query = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(sql)
            .addScalar("policy", Hibernate.STRING)
            .addScalar("memberName", Hibernate.STRING)
            .addScalar("premium", Hibernate.BIG_DECIMAL)
            .addScalar("effectiveDate", Hibernate.DATE)
            .addScalar("newOrRenewal", Hibernate.CHARACTER)
            .addScalar("auditPayment", Hibernate.BIG_DECIMAL)
            .addScalar("auditRecieveable", Hibernate.BIG_DECIMAL)
            .addScalar("associationDues", Hibernate.BIG_DECIMAL)
            .addScalar("expenseConstant", Hibernate.BIG_DECIMAL)
            .addScalar("nsfFees", Hibernate.BIG_DECIMAL)
            .addScalar("lossControl", Hibernate.BIG_DECIMAL)
            .addScalar("premiumPayment", Hibernate.BIG_DECIMAL)
            .addScalar("totalPaid", Hibernate.BIG_DECIMAL)
            .addScalar("month", Hibernate.STRING)
            .addScalar("installment", Hibernate.STRING)
            .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(MonthlyReport.class));
    List<MonthlyReport> monthlyReport = query.setString("month", month)
            .setString("startPayDate", month + "/" + cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + year)
            .setString("endPayDate", month + "/" + cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + year)
            .setString("fundYear", fundYear)
            .list();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I inherited this project and have never worked with Java or Hibernate before, and this is a large codebase.  This could well be a rookie mistake I'm making.

Comment: Is MonthlyReport inner class? MonthlyReportContext$MonthlyReport?

Comment: Yes, it's an inner class.

Comment: I am not sure how Hibernate works with Inner class, I would make this as outer class and try, if possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Indeed, this instantiation can be done only when the instantiated class is not an inner class...

You can either refactor the inner class into a normal class or make it static.

Hope this helps a little :)!

Comment: static AND public